# How to send inter-process message?

Tags: c, winapi

Both `PostMessage` and `SendNotifyMessage` fails with `ERROR_MESSAGE_SYNC_ONLY`. So my only option left is `SendMessage` but it doesn't seem to be doing anything - it returns zero and `GetLastError` is `ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND`.

Here is my sender code (process 1):

```
SendMessage(FindWindowEx(HWND_MESSAGE,NULL,"Message","serverwindow"),WM_COPYDATA,HWND_MESSAGE,
        &(COPYDATASTRUCT){0, sizeof "localhost", "localhost"})
```

And the receiver (process 0):

```
HWND hWnd=CreateWindowExA(0,"Message","serverwindow",0,0,0,0,0,HWND_MESSAGE,NULL,GetModuleHandle(NULL),NULL);
MSG msg;
while (Sleep(500), true)
while (PeekMessage(&msg,hWnd,0,0,PM_REMOVE))
    printf("message recieved\n");
```

Comment: Nested API calls.  Great.  How do you know which call is failing?  Stop writing 'clever' code and think about ease of debugging instead.  Use an  intermediate hwnd temp var instead of nesting.

Comment: @MartinJames By using powerful tools like IDA Pro. But that is beside the point - why isn't my server receiving the message? I tried `GetMessage` instead of `PeekMessage` as well but it's still not catching anything

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions - why you not debug your code (both server and client) ?. remove sleep. replace `PeekMessage` to `GetMessage`

Comment: `SendMessage()` does not report `ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND` on error, which implies that your error handling is wrong. You are likely calling `GetLastError()` too late, after another API has been called that resets the error code. `GetLastError()` must be called *immediately* after a failed API call that reports errors via `GetLastError()` (not all APIs do) before any other APIs are called.

Comment: `WM_COPYDATA` is known to work fine in general across process boundaries, so either `FindWindowEx()` is returning NULL, or the message is being blocked by UIPI. Also, `&(COPYDATASTRUCT){...}` is illegal in C++ (not sure about C), you should use an actual variable instead.

Comment: WM_COPYDATA is a sent message. Doesn't get queued. So the code here can never receive it. Handle it in the receiving window's window proc.

Comment: I'm not sure `HWND_MESSAGE` is a valid `wParam` value for the `WM_COPYDATA` message. It's meant to be an actual window handle afaik.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This comment should be an answer.

Comment: @zett42 Well, it's one problem of many, and I can't be bothered to try to answer them all. Answer one, and then the response will be, "I did X, and it still doesn't work"

Comment: @JonathanPotter the HWND passed in the `wParam` of `WM_COPYDATA` is arbitrary, it can be anything the sender wants, even 0. It is merely a convenience to allow the receiver to send a reply back to the sender, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

As David stated in a comment, `WM_COPYDATA` is a *sent* message, it is not a *queued* message, so a message loop like you have shown will never see the message being output by `(Get|Peek)Message()`.  The message is delivered directly to the `WindowProc` of the receiving window, so that is where it needs to be handled instead.  However, when sending a message across thread/process boundaries, the receiving thread does still need to run a message loop in order for *sent* messages to be dispatched to that thread's windows while `(Get|Peek)Message()` is waiting for a *queued* message.

Per the [`SendMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) documentation:

> Sends the specified message to a window or windows. **The SendMessage function calls the window procedure for the specified window and does not return until the window procedure has processed the message.**
>
> ...
>
> If the specified window was created by the calling thread, the window procedure is called immediately as a subroutine. **If the specified window was created by a different thread, the system switches to that thread and calls the appropriate window procedure. Messages sent between threads are processed only when the receiving thread executes message retrieval code. The sending thread is blocked until the receiving thread processes the message.** However, the sending thread will process incoming nonqueued messages while waiting for its message to be processed. To prevent this, use [SendMessageTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644952(v=VS.85).aspx) with SMTO_BLOCK set. For more information on nonqueued messages, see [Nonqueued Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927(v=VS.85).aspx).